# wp db request without refreshing the page

Tags: plugins, wpdb

want to make database requests like for example "select * from wp_users" to the database without refreshing the page.   I am in a wordpress plugin.
Have try already a few things and seem not to be working, for example to have this on the page I have on the plugin

```html
<!-- Add this to your WordPress template file where you want the AJAX request triggering button to appear -->
<button id="myButton">Make AJAX Request</button>

<!-- Add a div where you want to display the AJAX response -->
<div id="responseContainer"></div>

<!-- Add the AJAX script -->
<script>
// Add this code to your JavaScript file or in a <script> tag in your plugin file
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#myButton").on("click", function() {
        // Make an AJAX request to fetch data from the database
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, // ajaxurl is a global JavaScript variable in WordPress that holds the URL to admin-ajax.php
            type: 'POST', // Use POST method
            data: {
                'action': 'my_database_query' // Specify the AJAX action
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Handle the successful response here
                console.log(response); // Log the response to the console
                // You can update the DOM with the retrieved data as needed
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle errors here
                console.error(status + ': ' + error); // Log the error to the console
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and then having this on the index.php of the plugin

```php
// Register AJAX action for logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_my_database_query', 'my_database_query_callback');

function my_database_query_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // WordPress database access abstraction layer

    // Perform the database query
    $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users}");

    // Return the results as JSON
    wp_send_json($users);

    // Always use die() or exit() after wp_send_json()
    die();
}
```

any help its very welcome

Comment: the code in your question is attempting to use the old admin AJAX API, and it's bypassing the user APIs to query the database directly rather than using functions such as `get_users` or the `WP_User_Query` class. Is there a reason you aren't using the modern Users REST API endpoint instead? All this data is already provided by WordPress at `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` in JSON format for this very purpose

Comment: just asked gpt and got this answer, normally i know what i am doing but in this case i dont seem to find a lot of info about.

Comment: your answer already seems to have value info, checking about it.  I know how to do it using php, but I believe wordpress has this already figure it out and i dont need to re-event the wheel

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer, generally if you need to write a raw SQL query for a WP table then it's a major warning something has gone wrong and you should step back and think if this is the right way to do thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying the database directly, you could use `WP_User_Query`, but you'll get the best results by querying the REST API endpoint with a `GET` request at `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` which already lists out the users in a WordPress install. Just remember to account for pagination.